# Dynamic SQL query for custom columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Background:** an MSSQL DB (MS SQL Server 2017 with Entity Framework 6.1.3 as ORM) has an `Orders` table with the following columns: *ID, Order Number, Sender*, etc. There's another table that contains user defined data, meaning the end-users can create custom properties that are displayed from this table when an order is opened up. This `CustomData` table has the following structure: *ID, OrderID, CustomDataID, DataName, DataValue* with the *OrderID* column being a foreign key referencing the *ID* column of the `Orders` table.

Users first see a list of orders on the UI and they can open them with a double click. When an order opens up, a property page displays all custom data related to the order from the `CustomData` table.

**Requirement:** users requested that some of the custom properties are to be displayed in the order list itself, so they can be readily visible and be sorted. They want to pick on a per-user basis which additional columns are displayed (yes, they want 2-4 extra columns, depending on their task). And here lies the problem. I need to design a query that can retrieve a list of orders with the extra columns in the list. For example I could need to display a list with the following columns:

- Order Number
- Sender
- DataValue WHERE OrderID=10 AND CustomDataID=20
- DataValue WHERE OrderID=11 AND CustomDataID=21
- DataValue WHERE OrderID=12 AND CustomDataID=22

**The problem:** I suspect this will not be solvable with EF, which I do not mind as we have SQL scripts already in places where using EF would prove too tricky. I am OK with constructing a dynamic query from strings. But I have no Idea how to tackle the problem. A simple join will not do, due to the structure of the `CustomData` table.

Do I need to use two separate queries: one for the `Orders` and one for the `CustomData` table and merge them on the client side? Or is there a best practice for this type of issue? Do I need to refactor the DB?

Comment: You have more than enough rep around here to know this is not a good question. Post the table definition and some sample data along with the desired output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some inspiration.

Comment: I think if I were tackling this I would not use different queries. Instead I would hide or display columns on the client side when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot construct a single query and that is the problem. If I could find a way to add the CustomData columns then I would be game. I didn't post the DB structure as I suspected that the posted schema was enough to understand the problem.

Comment: So instead of making it easy for people to help you expect to parse through your text and assemble a table on our own? Then create a query against non-existent tables. Good luck with that. As I said previously I would not do this in the database. Just hide columns on the client side when you don't want them.